# Do outer regular outer measures always measure open sets?

Tags: measure-theory, gn.general-topology

Let $ \;  \langle X,\mathcal{T} \hspace{.06 in} \rangle  \;  $ be a second-countable Hausdorff space.

Let $ \;  \phi : 2^X \to [0,+\infty] \;  $ be an outer regular [outer measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Formal_definitions).

Does it follow that all open subsets of $X$ are [Caratheodory-measurable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Formal_definitions) by $\phi$ ?

(I already know this holds if $ \;  \langle X,\mathcal{T} \hspace{.06 in} \rangle  \;  $ is regular and $ \;  \phi(X) < +\infty  \;  $ .)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Suppose there is a set $E$ that is not measurable. Take the topology that is generated by $E$ and the original topology. This is also second countable and $\phi$ is regular for it.